# system.runtime.serialization and mvvmcross

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross, portable-class-library

I am stuck with this issue and I cant seem to solve it. I have my logic in a PCL and a a .Droid and .iOS clients.

I need to use the [serializable] attribute in my logic so I need to add a reference to system.runtime.serialization. The problem is there is a different dll for android and iOS how can I manage this? I did not encounter this problem before because I used shared files between the projects so each project had its own reference to the correct system.runtime.serialization and I could use the [serializable] attribute with no problems.

Have I missed something?

Thanks

Amit

Comment: I might suggest coming to the conclusion I have, which is "don't use PCL's" :).  Especially if it's just your code and you are splitting between Xamarin.iOS/Droid, you'll save hair just sharing .cs files.

Comment: @Erik Kerber have you encountered any other problems with PCL's?

Comment: Mind sharing why do you need ```SerializableAttribute```? Unless you're sharing your code with ASP.NET or something similar that does implicit serialization of your classes, there are ways to go on without it.

Comment: @Amit You've already seen it, it's much easier to share code than it is to share assemblies.  Why limit your code to whatever is supported by PCL's when you can have the full power of your platform instead? In most cases, any difference in platforms can be resolved with #ifdefs.  PCL's are useful if you are making a library meant to be consumed by others and a single .dll is convenient. If you are just working on your own project, then code sharing to me is by far the best option.

Answer (score 2):

In general I'd recommend avoiding trying to use the `SerializableAttribute` in portable code.  That type of serialization is basically not portable.  However, if you really need to do it, that attribute is actually treated specially and is represented by a bit on the type as opposed to a normal attribute.  So if you define your own attribute with the same name and namespace in a PCL, the compiler will emit the bit and everything may just work like you need it to.

Comment: What is the recommended way to do serialization in a PCL?

Comment: @pauldendulk DataContract serializatioon, or Json.NET